# Node js database connection in a separate module

Tags: javascript, node.js, db2

I made node.js app that includes some REST services. Those services connect to a database (for example Oracle or DB2) to execute some query.

Since I'm a beginner in node.js programming, I have a question about my case:
What's the right way to access to a database? Is it better to have one connection reference while the app is running and use the same connection instance when REST services are called?

I found some examples that includes database connection in a separate module and use that module in app, something like that:

db2.js:

```
var db2 = require('ibm_db');

var db2ConnSettings = "DRIVER={DB2};DATABASE=mydb;HOSTNAME=localhost;UID=db2test;PWD=db2test;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP";

var db2Conn = db2.open(db2ConnSettings, function(err, conn) {
        if (err)
            return console.log(err);
    });

module.exports = db2Conn;
```

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var db2Connection = require('./db2.js');

app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    console.log(db2Connection );
    // make some query
});
```

When this service is called, `db2connection` is `undefined`. How come? How should I retrieve a db2 connection from `db2.js` file?

Comment: the problem is, that your database connection is set up asynchronously. You get the actual connection as the `conn` parameter in the callback and not as synchronous return value of `.open()`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ibm_db`, but I'd suggest some basic debugging to figure out what's going on. Add some `console.log`s to different places, like in db2.js to see if it's loaded in the first place, then log out dbConn to see if `db2.open` returned a value.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat I already did that and it's `undefined` in `db2.js`, too. So I believe that it really has something to do with callback, but I can't really make it work in `server.js` file.

Comment: You said "db2connection is undefined" which is after db2.js is required, in server.js only. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by @Sirko:

## db2.js

```
var db2 = require('ibm_db');
var db2ConnSettings = "DRIVER={DB2};DATABASE=mydb;HOSTNAME=localhost;UID=db2test;PWD=db2test;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP";

var err, conn;
var callbacks = [];

module.exports = function(callback) {
  // db2 module is called

  if (err || conn) {
    // connection has already been established
    //   (results of db2.open have been stored)
    // callback immediately
    callback(err, conn);
  }
  else {
    // connection has not been established
    // store the callback for when db connects
    callbacks.push(callback);
  }
};

db2.open(db2ConnSettings, function(_err, _conn){
  // db has connected

  err = _err; conn = _conn; // store results
  var next_callback;

  // array.pop() removed the last item from the array
  // and returns it. if no items are left, returns null.
  // so this loops through all stored callbacks.
  while(next_callback = callbacks.pop()) {
    // the removed item is stored in next_callback
    next_callback(err, conn); // send connection results to callback
  }

  // no more items in callbacks to trigger
});
```

## server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var db2Connection = require('./db2.js')(function(err, conn) {
  // triggered if the connection has already been established
  // or as soon as it HAS been established
  app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
      console.log(conn);
      // ...
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure, if the solution is that simple as here each time the function is called a new database connection is established. So depending on the rest of the code, you can end up with LOTS of connections.

Comment: Fair enough. I've updated it with a simple promises-like system.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat thanks, it worked. Would you mind adding some comment to that code? I'd like to understand what it does...

Comment: Does that help? I've changed some variable names to be clearer also.

Answer (score 2):

For [Oracle with node-oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb) it's simple to create and use a connection pool.  Your app would just get a free connection from the pool whenever it handles an HTTP REST request. Look at `webapp.js` and `webapppromises.js` in the [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples).  Node-oracledb has a 'connection pool queue' (see [doc](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md)) which handles connection load spikes.  It also has a 'connection pool cache' (also see the doc) which makes it easy to access a pool created in a different module.

Comment: I guess if an app uses just a few connections in a short period, there's no need to create a connection pool, right? What's the most common approach in that case? If I have multiple REST services with database access, should I create a new connection each time a service is called or should I use the same connection reference?

Comment: I'd probably go with a small pool.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion!